# No sound in TES:Arena with DosBox

Tags: dosbox, the-elder-scrolls-arena

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No sound in TES:Arena under DOSBox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50873/no-sound-in-tesarena-under-dosbox)

I recently downloaded TES Arena from TES website and I tried to play it with DOSBOX. Everything works fine exept sound. I have no sound at all. I read that if I started arena.bat instead of a.exe it would work but actually I just get a black screen with 2 weird sumbols on the upper left corner. I have Windows 7 64bit. I have done quite a bit of reaserch but I just cant get it working... Anyone can help?

Comment: It seems like you didn't install the game properly. Refer to [this page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/General:Playing_DOS_Installments_under_DOSBox) or use the [pre-made installer](http://wiwiki.wiwiland.net/index.php?title=Arena_:_ArenaSetup_EN) (3d party, unofficial) instead.